# Cassini (Soldner) in pyproj

Tags: python, coordinate-system, proj, pyproj

So there is the cassini projection in Proj. It is possible to use it in the OSGeo4WShell.
example: +proj=cass +lon_0=.... +lat_0=.... +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs

Is there a way to define such CRS in Python?

example for ecef system: ecef = pyproj.Proj(proj='geocent', ellps='WGS84', datum='WGS84')

But I want to use the cassini projection (to transform to ecef).

How do I define it?

Is CAssini implemented in pyproj?

Answer (score 1):

pyproj is a python wrapper for PROJ. PROJ currently supports cassini, so pyproj should as well (https://proj.org/operations/projections/cass.html).

You likely want the CRS and Transformer classes:

```py
import pyproj

cass = pyproj.CRS("+proj=cass +lon_0=.... +lat_0=.... +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +units=m")
ecef = pyproj.CRS(proj='geocent', ellps='WGS84', datum='WGS84')
transformer = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(cass, ecef)
```

Also see: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/examples.html